# Heroku:Custom Domain , ACM status:DNS redirect not forwarding path,What to do?

Tags: spring, heroku, dns

this is the first time i am buying a custom domain and i want to access my heroku java spring app by using the new domain name instead of the one provided by heroku.

The problem is that i get a ACM status:DNS redirect not forwarding path exception in heroku domain table,so it does not work.And i also do not know what this is and how to fix it even if i looked here https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/automated-certificate-management#view-your-certificate-status

**What i did so far:**

I bought a custom domain name from godaddy.

Then i went to heroku settings >domains>add domain.

After that i got a new domain in the table.

I went to godaddy Records in order to add a new CNAME where i have added the domain name as name ( mycustomdomain. com) and the very long DNS Target that was autogenerated by heroku as value.

Now i went back to heroku and this ACM Status message is displayed:
`DNS redirect not forwarding path`

What am i missing?What do i have to do next to be able to successfully connect the 2 parts?
I saw some post arround here with "redirecting" but i am not sure if that applies to me or not.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're not already doing so, the host name for the CNAME record should be 'www' - and then the 'points to' would obviously be the URL Heroku gave you.

On the Heroku side, where you have listed the domain name itself, make sure to include the www. on the address itself - This is something I neglected to do a few weeks ago, once i added it - everything started working correctly.

I came across your issue because i've added a second URL (.com variation) and i'm getting that message with this second domain - Like you i'm unsure what i have missed...